# can someone help me how do i put the output in array form without using built-in function

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
function filterRange(arr, min, max){
newArr = []
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
 if(arr[i] > min && arr[i] < max)
     newArr += arr[i];
}
return newArr;
}
filterRange([1,3,5,7,10], 4, 8);
filterRange([1,3,5,7,10], -1, 4);
filterRange([2,4,3,5], 2, 6);
```

/*OUTPUT THAT I GOT ARE:
57
13
435

it should return [5,7] , [1,3], [4,3,5]

*/

Comment: The Q+A suggested as a duplicate should show you why this didn't work.  But if you want a simpler version, [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) makes this almost trivial: `const filterRange = (arr, min, max) => arr .filter ((n) => n > min && n < max)`